# Regular expression gosu

Tags: regex, gosu

I need a regex for the following conditions.

- must not begin or end with the symbol: `/`
- must not contain two consecutive slash characters: `//`
- must not contain any of the following special characters:  `><?\|@’#~-_=+)(*^%$£”!`

I am specially stuck where I need to check if the string should not contain `//` i.e. consecutive slash characters.

- `.*//.*`  -- this is working for string having `//` but actually want negative of this regex.
- `.*[^//].*` -- this is not working..

I want to write it in Gosu. I suppose both languages have similar API but still good to mention.

Comment: I need, I need, I need - is not a question!

Comment: Tags [should not be added](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/) to the title. Could you please remove regex and gosu from the title?

Comment: Your list of forbidden characters includes `’` ( U+2019, Right Single Quotation Mark) and `”` (U+201D, Right Double Quotation Mark).  Is that correct, or did you mean `'` (apostrophe) and `"` (quotation mark)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need

```
 # ^[^>^%$£”!./](?:[/]?[^>^%$£”!./])*$

 ^ 
 [^>^%$£”!./] 
 (?: [/]? [^>^%$£”!./] )*
 $
```

Your new regex visa vie need more ..

```
 ^ 
 [a-zA-Z0-9] 
 (?: [/]? [^>^%$£”!./] )*
 (?<= [a-zA-Z0-9] )
 $
```

Comment: Im sorry but above regex is not wokring.

Comment: I have two regex with me
1) "[a-z A-Z 0-9]{1}[a-z A-Z 0-9 /]*[a-z A-Z 0-9]{1}" -  This whole string should not contain any special charater except '/' and must not start or end with anything other than alphanumeric.

2)"^((?!//).)*$" -  Must not contain consecutive /.

They are working perfectly when executed separately but I want all the condition in both the regex to be matched.

Any way we can combine both these regex??

Comment: Well, update your question with the added `begin/end with alpha-num`. If your `no special characters` list is still the same, then this is the regex with the extra begin/end alpha num: `^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[/]?[^>^%$£”!./])*(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])$` There we combined them!